# Select all records with same column value after search

Tags: mysql, sql, adonis.js

I have table called 'forms' that looks like this

| ID | entry_id | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | text |
| 2 | 1 | rand txt |
| 3 | 1 | another rand txt |
| 4 | 2 | new entry |

I need to search this table based on content (eg. `SELECT * FROM forms WHERE content LIKE 'text';`), and if the record is found, all other records with same `entry_id` need to be selected.

For example, if the record with ID 1 is found with search query, records with ID 2 and 3 should be selected as well since they belong to the same entry.

Answer (score 2):

One method uses `exists`:

```
select f.*
from forms f
where exists (select 1
              from forms f2
              where f2.id = f.id and
                    f.content like 'text'
             );
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select f.*
from (select f.*,
             sum( f.content like 'text' ) over (partition by id) as num_text
      from forms f
     ) f
where num_text > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t2.* 
FROM forms t1
JOIN forms t2 USING (entry_id) 
WHERE t1.content LIKE 'text';
```

Remember - LIKE without pattern symbols searches direct matching only (i.e. is equal to `=`).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM forms AS f1 INNER JOIN forms AS f2 ON f1.entry_id = f2.entry_id
WHERE f1.content LIKE 'text'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like this. You can use nested query.

```
SELECT * FROM forms
WHERE entry_id IN
(SELECT entry_id FROM forms WHERE content LIKE '%text%')
```